# A word for a statement that sounds true because it sounds good

Tags: single-word-requests

A statement that appears true mostly because it sounds good / poetic / alliterates / rhymes.

I'm pretty sure there is such a word. I heard it a few years ago, but have since forgotten it.

Answer (score 16):

Verisimilitude means "the quality of sounding true." So if you wanted to be very pretentious and formal about it you could say something like "verisimilitude by euphony."

(This example was recursive. :) )

Comment: I have no idea if this is accurate, but it just sounds *right*.  hee hee I love words that start with V!

Comment: Statements with verisimilitude usually *are* true - at least in the opinion of the speaker who dubs them with that quality. If I knew for sure the statement *wasn't* true, I'd probably say it was **seductive**.

Answer (score 4):

The newish word ["truthiness"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) sort of applies here but focuses more on gut feelings or things that just seem true instead of a statement's visual or oral attractiveness.

Answer (score 3):

The word you're looking for is [*specious*](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/specious).

Comment: Note that *specious* means something that isn't actually true. The way I interpret the question, it's looking for a word that doesn't say anything about the underlying truth value of a statement, just about whether it *sounds* true.

Comment: This seems to be the apt answer .. Just want to appreciate good answers...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something that would fall among the *logical fallacies*.

Perhaps "prestigious jargon": http://www.care2.com/c2c/groups/disc.html?gpp=18556&pst=904731

Or "appeal to emotion": http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/appeal-to-emotion.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of '[rhetoric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric)', or perhaps, '[sophism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophists)' or '[sophistry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophistry)'?

Answer (score 0):

truthlikeness (see the [Wikipedia entry on verisimilitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verisimilitude))